# Button used for navigation is not working after writing code for disabling button

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a view model that contains validation codes, and also has some code for disabling button when validation fails. I have window that contains fields for employee information, that window contains a save button and a button for navigate to another window.

However that button is not working after I written code for disabling button. I have bound the 'isenabled' property to some property that is used for disabling button. I didn't bind to button used for navigation. Why it is not working? I am using mvvm.

This is my code for disabling button

```
 public EmployeeViewModel()
        {
this.validProperties = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            this.validProperties.Add("FirstName", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("LastName", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("Street1", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("Street2", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("City", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("State", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("ZipCode", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("PhoneNumber", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("MobileNumber", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("Email", false);
            this.validProperties.Add("Web", false);      
    }

 public bool AllPropertiesValid
        {
            get { return allPropertiesValid; }
            set
            {
                if (allPropertiesValid != value)
                {
                    allPropertiesValid = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AllPropertiesValid");
                }
            }
        }

 private void ValidateProperties()
        {
            foreach (bool isValid in validProperties.Values)
            {
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    this.AllPropertiesValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            this.AllPropertiesValid = true;
        }

public string Error
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string strMessage = string.Empty;
                validateUserInput(ref strMessage, propertyName);
                validProperties[propertyName] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(strMessage) ? true : false;
                ValidateProperties();
                CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                return strMessage;
            }
        }

        private string validateUserInput(ref string pstrMessage, string pstrpropertyName)
        {
            switch (pstrpropertyName)
            {
                case "FirstName":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                        pstrMessage = "FirstName is required.";
                    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
                        pstrMessage = "Spaces are not allowed in First name. only character are allowed";
                    break;
                case "LastName":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                        pstrMessage = "LastName is required.";
                    break;
                case "Street1":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Street1))
                        pstrMessage = "Street1 is required";
                    break;
                case "Street2":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Street2))
                        pstrMessage = "Street2 is required";
                    break;
                case "City":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
                        pstrMessage = "City is required";
                    break;
                case "State":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(State))
                        pstrMessage = "State is required";
                    break;
                case "ZipCode":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode))
                        pstrMessage = "ZipCode is required";
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(employee.ZipCode, AppConstants.Regexpatterns.ZiCodeRegex) == false)
                        pstrMessage = "Only 6 digits are allowed in ZipCode field.";
                    break;
                case "PhoneNumber":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneNumber))
                        pstrMessage = "PhoneNumber is required";
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(employee.PhoneNumber, AppConstants.Regexpatterns.PhoneNumberRegex) == false)
                        pstrMessage = "Enter a valid PhoneNumber.";
                    break;
                case "MobileNumber":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MobileNumber))
                        pstrMessage = "MoblieNumber is required";
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(employee.MobileNumber, AppConstants.Regexpatterns.PhoneNumberRegex) == false)
                        pstrMessage = "Enter a valid MobileNumber.";
                    break;
                case "Email":
                    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email)))
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(Email, AppConstants.Regexpatterns.EmailRegex) == false)
                            pstrMessage = "Enter a valid EmailID.";
                    break;
                case "Web":
                    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Web)))
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(Web, AppConstants.Regexpatterns.WebRegex) == false)
                            pstrMessage = "Enter a valid Web Address.";
                    break;
            }
            return pstrMessage;
        }
```

This is my XAML for save button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="3"  Width="47" Name="btnAdd" Content="ADD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="22"  Background="Black" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding SaveEmployeeCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=AllPropertiesValid}"></Button>
```

This is my XAML for navigate button:

```
 <Button Content="Home" Name="btnHome" Margin="440,0,-4,465" Command="{Binding HomeCommand}" Background="#FF2693A7" Foreground="White"  />
```

Comment: What type of commands and MVVM framework are you using? Certain implementations of commands (e.g. DelegateCommand in MvvmLight) provide "can execute" logic that you would want to use to disable your button. Also, you may want to consider using a data annotation or business object/rules framework that makes this validation a lot easier on you. That said, it isn't immediately obvious why it is failing to work properly in this case, since your OnPropertyChanged looks good. (Note: you can use the attribute [CallerMemberName] on the OnPropertyChanged argument in .NET 4.5 to avoid magic strings.)

Comment: What do you have in the HomeCommand()

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that your `<Button Content="Home" />` button is disabled, the only reason I see is that you have binded the Command to it and if that `Command has CanExecute` then returning false from `CanExecute` Disables the button.

Comment: that button hasnt can execute